# Return all rows from the left table, and distinct matched rows from the right table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**W3schools**:

> LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows
>   from the right table

**Target**: Add a single column from the right table

**Challenge**: the right table has many repeated rows

**Goal**: Would like the join to return the exact number of rows as in the left table, or in other words, the distinct matched rows from the right table

**Example Update**:

There are too many customers for each image, so a single ImageID could be repeated. I would like to return a single one from the Customers side.

```
SELECT Images.ImageID, Customers.BooleanColumn 
FROM Images
LEFT JOIN Customers
ON Images.ImageID = Customers.ImageID
```

Comment: you need to come up with example data... If you want exactly to match, why not `inner join`?

Comment: How would I know? Your question has no information at all so it was my wild guess. In all seriousness I can think of several ways to accomplish this but it all depends on the actual details.

Comment: Unfortunately, whatever info is there is not enough to understand the logic going on in your mind :) Consider adding more details for better answers from community; Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It has a vague description of a problem yes...but that is not enough information to be considered a complete question.

Comment: Good grief...your comments are as vague as your question. If you were a client I would be elated to collect so many billable hours while I extract the details of what is likely a simple solution. But as I am offering my time for free....your timer of my time is about to expire.

Comment: If you would like all records from the first table (call it TABLE_A) and only those distinct matches from the second table (call it TABLE_B) you can use a group by clause along with your table join.  You have to be careful which columns you group from TABLE_B in this case as they will impact how many rows are returned

Comment: @usefulBee I wasn't complaining. I was trying to get you to realize that you didn't provide enough information for anybody to offer any real help. Even with more "details" it isn't really clear what you want. From your example if you had more than 1 customer for an image which customer would you want? The first one? You would have to define first. You could probably do this using cross apply with a top 1 but you would need to define an order by. Despite you being snarky with somebody offering to help you I will post an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to group your result set against ImageID and BooleanColumn use the below script.

```
    SELECT Images.ImageID, Customers.BooleanColumn 
    FROM Images
        LEFT JOIN Customers
             ON Images.ImageID = Customer.ImageID
   Group by  Images.ImageID, Customers.BooleanColumn
```

If you wanted to check atleast one of the customer linked to the ImageID , use any of the below script.

```
     SELECT DISTINCT ImageID
          , ( case when Customers.ImageId is null Then 0 Else 1) BooleanValue
     FROM Images
         LEFT JOIN Customers
             ON Images.ImageID = Customers.ImageID
```

OR

```
    SELECT ImageId,
                ISNULL (  (Select 1 from customers c
                    Where c.imageId=I.imageid),0)BooleanValue 
    FROM Images I
```

Answer (score 0):

There still is no sample data to work with or desired results. These are considered a fundamental element of an online question such as this. As such this code is untested but it should provide what I think you are looking for.

```
select i.ImageID
    , c.BooleanColumn
from Images i
outer apply
(
    select top 1 BooleanColumn
    from Customers c2
    order by c2.CustomerID --or whatever column you need for ordering
) c
```